# Android Studioで文字化けが起こる

Tags: android-studio, 文字化け

先ほどAndroid Studioを起動した所、至る所のファイルが文字化けしていました。
前回起動した時は問題ありませんでしたし、Android Studioの設定は特に変更していないのですが…
Android Studioを使用せず、ソースコードを見てみると正しく表示され、また、新規プロジェクトを作成しても文字化けが起こっています。
環境はWindows 8.1 x64でAndroid Studio 1.0.2です。
[image]

Comment: スクリーンショットに表示されている文字列の一部で[ググる](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?q=lagf+9j+af9d#q=lagf+9j+af9d)と、色んなpdfファイルがヒットしますね

Comment: どのファイルを開いてもすべて同じ見た目ですか？ファイルごとに多少は異なりますか？

Comment: @ento さん
そのようですね、何故それらがヒットするのかちょっと良くわかりませんが…。

Comment: @fliedonion さん
ファイルごとにというかファイル関係なしにもともと同じ文字列だったものは同じように文字化けして表示されます。
それと、文字化けした文字をコピーして、テキストエディタなどに貼り付けると、元の文字に変換されています…。
また、日本語は文字化けしていないようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

検索するとたしかにpdfがヒットはしますね、レンダリング絡みなのでしょうか。

自信はないですが日本語は表示されるということなので、
エディタのフォントやアンチエイリアスを変更してみるなにか変わるかもしれません。

設定箇所ですが、以下で変更できます。

**Fontの変更**

メニューから File > Settings で設定画面を開きます。
 (または`Ctrl+Alt+S`か、`Ctrl+Shift+A`からSettingsなど入力してアクションを選択でも開けます）

検索フィールドにFontを入力するか、Editor > Colors & Fots > Font をたどって、Font設定に行きます。
デフォルト設定は変更できないので、Save Asで自分用設定をつくり、フォントを変更します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**Anti-Aliasオフ**

同様にSettingsを開き、検索フィールドに`anti`と入力して、右側に表示された`Use anti-aliased font`をオフにする

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Fontの変更で治りました！ありがとうございます。Source Code Proを使っていたのですが、それがなぜかAndroid Studio上で突然文字化けするようになっていたようでした。